# What to do with insignificant regressors in a VECM?

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, regression-coefficients, vector-error-correction-model

I'm forecasting electricity demand based on GDP and population. For the series that there is a unit root I have conducted the Johansen cointegration test and applied the number of cointegrating equations to the VECM.

When I get the results from the VECM, I perform an OLS to find the coefficients. My question is, what should I do with the coefficients with high p-value (C(4) and C(6)). Should I exclude these coefficients and rerun the model or should I accept them as well in my analysis for the forecast?

Overall the R-square is 0.758 which is a good result and also the Prob(F-statistic) is 0.00.

```
Dependent Variable: D(ELEC)             
Method: Least Squares               
Date: 08/17/16   Time: 13:34                
Sample (adjusted): 1974 2013                
Included observations: 40 after adjustments             
D(ELEC) = C(1)*( ELEC(-1) - 1.78078157078*POP(-1) + 4.86087264791 ) +               
        C(2)*( GDP(-1) - 3.51459703515*POP(-1) + 8.23177201198 ) + C(3)             
        *D(ELEC(-1)) + C(4)*D(ELEC(-2)) + C(5)*D(GDP(-1)) + C(6)*D(GDP(             
        -2)) + C(7)*D(POP(-1)) + C(8)*D(POP(-2)) + C(9)             

Coefficient Std. Error  t-Statistic Prob.  

C(1)    -0.211084   0.094992    -2.222125   0.0337

C(2)    0.068551    0.023368    2.933587    0.0063

C(3)    0.558926    0.183732    3.042079    0.0048

C(4)    0.301294    0.227807    1.322582    0.1956

C(5)    -0.056782   0.026318    -2.157586   0.0388

C(6)    -0.040041   0.022045    -1.816334   0.0790

C(7)    -49.45054   15.47998    -3.194482   0.0032

C(8)    44.98846    14.64799    3.071306    0.0044

C(9)    0.550806    0.226170    2.435359    0.0208

R-squared           0.758225        Mean dependent var      0.231150
Adjusted R-squared  0.695831        S.D. dependent var      0.217092
S.E. of regression  0.119730        Akaike info criterion  -1.212055
Sum squared resid   0.444390        Schwarz criterion      -0.832057
Log likelihood      33.24111        Hannan-Quinn criter.   -1.074660
F-statistic         12.15227        Durbin-Watson stat      1.844170
Prob(F-statistic)   0.000000
```

Comment: You could look up existing threads on what to do with insignificant regressors and see if you find a good answer. VECM is nothing special when it comes to regressor significance, so you could consider answers that are not necessarily targeted to VECM. (5 minutes later: After a little bit of search I have to admit I did not find a good thread to address your question. But probably I am just bad at searching.)

Comment: After some research online I found that there seems to be a guideline that 50% of the coefficients should be significant as well as the R-squared and prob(F-statistics) should be significant. Is there anyone else who concur with these guidelines?

Comment: There are many rules of thumb but none works in all cases. What you could do is see if excluding variables decreases AIC. If it does, go with it, because AIC is what you should look at when focusing on forecasting.